# Difficulty in plotting 2 degree linear regression

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, linear-regression, curve

I'm facing some trouble while plotting a 2d linear regression with a 2 degree curve from a Machine Learning model.

Here is my code:

```
m = 100
X = 6 * np.random.rand(m, 1) - 3

y = 0.5 * X**2 + X + 2 + np.random.randn(m, 1)
plt.plot(X, y, "b.")
plt.show()
```

Until here ok, this is my scatterplot:

[image]

Now I'm training a 2 degree linear model.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

poly_features = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2, include_bias=False)
X_poly = poly_features.fit_transform(X)

lin_reg = LinearRegression()
lin_reg.fit(X_poly, y)
```

Model trained.

And this is my result when I plot the curve:

```
plt.plot(X, lin_reg.predict(X_poly), "r-")
plt.show()
```

[image]

I'm figuring out how to print the continuous curve, and not those line-connected points.

Below is my desired output, manually draw.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You're going to kick yourself, probably
- Everything is fine, except `X` needs to be sorted with [`numpy.sort()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html).

  - The lines are drawn in order, from point to point. Since the points are not ordered by `X`, they're drawn all over.
- `np.random.seed(365)` has been specified to produce the same values each time.

```py
import numpy
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

m = 100
np.random.seed(365)
X = 6 * np.random.rand(m, 1) - 3
X = np.sort(X, axis=0)  # sort the values

y = 0.5 * X**2 + X + 2 + np.random.randn(m, 1)

# regression code
poly_features = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2, include_bias=False)
X_poly = poly_features.fit_transform(X)

lin_reg = LinearRegression()
lin_reg.fit(X_poly, y)

# plot
plt.plot(X, y, "b.")
plt.plot(X, lin_reg.predict(X_poly), "r-")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Great, tha's exactly what I was looking for. So, the reason is just because of random was not showing me `X` as a sorted array. Thanks a lot!